# How to return filtered object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have object `dropdownOptions` and i have `totalItem`

[image]

I need to do this:

- If `12 < totalItems < 24` show "Show 12, Show 24"
- If `24 < totalItems < 36` show only "Show 12, Show 24, Show 36"

And so on. I try to use computed property, but how to work with this conditions in object

```
const dropdownOptions = {
 12: "Show 12",
 24: "Show 24",
 36: "Show 36",
 48: "Show 48",
}

const totalItem = 19

const dropdownOptionFiltered = computed(() => {
 if (dropdownOptions) {}
 return dropdownOption
})
```

Comment: Your condition doesn't make sense: for "Show 12" and "Show 24", shouldn't the condition just be `12 < totalItems < 36`?

Comment: So if ```totalItems``` will be 9, so should "show 12"

Comment: `dropdownOptions` need to remain an object? Seems an array would fit this better. Otherwise check out `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`.

Comment: @bernardi Your required output is not clear to me and it's confusing. Can you please elaborate the expected output.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal If totalItem = 10 => dropdownOptions {12: "show 12"}, totalItem = 25 => dropdownOptions {12: "show 12", 24: "show 24"}

Comment: @bernardi If on 10 we are showing `Show 12`, why on 25 we are not showing `Show 36` ? Still your requirement is not clear.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal Oh my mistake sorry, i edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const dropdownOptions = {
  12: "show 12",
  24: "show 24",
  36: "show 36",
  48: "show 48",
}

const totalItem = 19

const dropdownOptionFiltered = () => {
  let num = Object.keys(dropdownOptions).filter(x => x < totalItem).length + 1
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(dropdownOptions).slice(0, num)
  )
}
console.log(dropdownOptionFiltered())
```